# Notation for defining a set of distinct elements.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Suppose I write the following.

> Let $X = \{x,y,z\}.$

Then its pretty clear that what I *really* mean is the following.

> Let $x,y$ and $z$ be fixed but arbitrary; **suppose they're distinct**; and let $X = \{x,y,z\}$.

Not that its really necessary or anything, but if there is an established convention for emphasizing that what I *really* mean is the second of these, then I'd like to start using it. Something like the following.

> Let $X \equiv \{x,y,z\}.$

Does any such notational convention currently exist?

Comment: A [set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)), by definition, cannot contain multiple or repeated elements. See [multiset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset).

Comment: @Lucian, so? A fairly typical definition of $\{x,y,z\}$ would be $\{x\} \cup \{y\} \cup \{z\}$.

Comment: $X=\{x,y,z\}$ , $\text{card }X=3$ ?

Comment: @Lucian, I like it!

Comment: If $X$ is a subset of a set $E$, you could write $X=\{x,y,z\}\in[E]^3$ or $X=\{x,y,z\}\in\binom E3$, if you are using $[E]^3$ or $\binom E3$ for the set of all $3$-element subsets of $E$.

Comment: @Lucian We know that a set cannot contain repeated elements, but that doesn't mean that we know if a set denoted by the expression $\{x,y,z\}$ has cardinality $3$ or $2$ or $1$.

Comment: There is the following notational convention: $$x,y,z\text{ distinct elements}, X=\{x,y,z\}$$ Kinda long, though. But I like it. It's completely clear, and you don't have to add more symbols to your dictionary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I've seen the notation $X=\{x,y,z\}_\ne$ used to indicate that $X$ is the set containing the distinct elements $x,y,z$; probably in some old paper by Erdős, Rado, and Hajnal, or some subset thereof. I know for a fact that the notation $\{x_0,x_1,\dots\}_\lt$ has been used to denote the set $\{x_0,x_1,\dots\}$ while expressing the fact that $x_0\lt x_1\lt\dots$; this notation is introduced on p. 428 of P. Erdős amd R. Rado, A partition calculus in set theory, Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. 62 (1956), 427-489. Most likely the notation was Rado's invention. I don't know to what extent it has caught on.

I think Rado's(?) notation has the advantage over your $X\equiv\{x,y,z\}$ in that the meaning is easier to remember or guess; also you can simply write $\{x,y,z\}_\ne$ without necessarily having "$X=$" in front of it.

**Update.** Quoting from L. Mirsky, *Transversal Theory*, Academic Press, 1971, p. 2:

> We shall use the symbol $\{x_1,\dots,x_k\}_\ne$ to denote the set consisting of the elements $x_1,\dots,x_k$ and at the same time express the fact that these elements are distinct. If the suffix '$\ne$' is not appended to the curly bracket, then no assumption is made about the distinctness of the elements listed.